# Ill Met By Moonlight Sinding Bug

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I went and killed the stag to talk to Hircine. Then, when I went to the grotto Sinding wasn't there, he was on the road to Whiterun from Riverwood. I went to where he was but before I got there I was turned to a werewolf by the ring. I decided I'd keep going because I should've reverted by the time I got to him. I didn't and when I got to him he started running off towards the grotto.

When I got there after him and went inside, I didn't get the conversation with him on the rock. I managed to catch him before he killed all the hunters and agreed to help him. After we killed them, he started attacking me. No matter what I tried it wouldn't let me talk to him. I think me being a werewolf when I met him outside bugged the quest. I ended up killing him and got the hide from Hircine. I was wanting to get the ring but I didn't know what else I could try and I had no save to go back to before I met him because I'm really bad at saving frequently, I usually rely on autosave unless it's at an important part I don't want to mess up.

Does anyone know of if there was a way to calm him down and talk to him? It doesn't really help me now but if it ever happens again I'd like to know what I can do.

Comment: Using the "Calm" spell (or any variation of that spell) on him might help in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

All elder scroll games are extremely glitchy and most quests have some glitch, if not 10. There are two  things I learned early  on while playing them:

1. Save often
2. Create many saves

I generally save about every 15 to 20 minutes so I have many places to back up to in the case of glitches. Also, I would suggest that you turn on the "SAVE ON TRAVEL" option. This saves every time you go through door with a load screen or fast travel.

Comment: But as the OP said "it doesn't really help me now, but if it ever happens again I'd like to know what to do." This was the question I was answering. What the OP could do in the future to help.

Comment: The OP seems to want a solution to future problem like this rather than a solution to this problem

Comment: I was reading the question more as "how can I calm someone down in the future" but I guess this works, too. Didn't read the question closely enough, I guess.

Comment: Rereading over this. I can see your point too. It seems he is asking two questions. How to calm someone and how to prevent this from happening in the future?